# Overleaf in VIM mode not allowing caps lock to return to normal mode

Tags: overleaf

So im trying to get started using overleaf as its recommended on one of my courses, but for some reason Overleafs VIM mode is not detecting the escape key properly. Im on Ubuntu 20.04 and ive swapped escape and caps lock using `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape`. But if im in Overleaf insert mode, pressing caps lock does not return me to Normal mode. Only way to go back to normal mode is by pressing the esc key, which also toggles caps lock on. Its very frustrating and not usable.

Any ideas what I could do to fix it?

Comment: Remark. it might work to remap at the hardware (scan codes) level. E.g. [Map scancodes to keycodes - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes) (guide for Arch but might be applicable to Ubuntu as well, I don't know)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
:imap jj <Esc>
```

To escape to normal mode by pressing j twice.

Comment: not what im looking for

Comment: Questions like this are best sent to Overleaf support (support@overleaf.com). I'm on the Overleaf support team, and we're happy to answer these kinds of questions. Briefly: Overleaf won't detect settings you've configured via setxkbmap. The vim and emacs keybindings are a more limited emulation of those, and are provided via an open source library (currently https://ace.c9.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Remapping the escape key did the trick for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/239542)

Comment: While this might answer the question, it's quite unclear what is the suggestion exactly. As the OP mentions, they already tried to remap escape key by switching it to caps lock.

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please Edit your answer and outline a little, what or how to do what you propose?